# Как открыть одно приложение через другое?

Tags: c#, c++, c, windows, sandbox

Всем привет!

Потребовалось реализовать открытие одного приложения в другом. Если клацаю по приложению пкм, то я смогу его отрыть в песочнице. Как реализовать тоже самое только в виде кода?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Интересует код на C#, однако можете предложить любое решение, интересна именно логика решения. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Для начала стоит разобраться, что же такое "песочница" в данном конкретном случае. А так `Process.Start(@"путь\файл.exe");`

Comment: Хм.. А я думал вопрос про то, как пункт в контекстное меню прописать.

Comment: Смотришь в реестре этот пункт - там будет выполняемая команда - а её в Process.Start.

Comment: @Qwertiy вот думаю в ту же сторону, только я совсем еще маленький и тупой. Подскажете где искать, что бы найти исполняемую команду?

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю поможет или нет, но вот как это делал я

```
System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "SnakeGIT.exe";
p.Start();
```

Но .exe у меня находился в корне приложения, можете попробовать перенести его туда или создать ярлык, или попробовать указать путь.